# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for Convergence to Standard Normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of iid random variable with density:
>   $$f(t)=c \frac{1}{|t|^{3+\alpha}}1_{\{|t| \ge 1 \}}\quad; t \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \alpha > 0$$
>
> Choose $\{B_n\}$ to be a sequence of positive reals such that 
>   $$\{B_n\} \to \infty \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$$
>
> Provide the necessary and sufficient conditions on the sequence $\{B_n\}$ so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{B_n}=N(0,1)$$ in distribution.

I am not sure **how to approach** this problem.  Should I be trying to calculate the characteristic function for $\displaystyle \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{B_n}$ and then attempting to deduce conditions based on that?

Comment: Not sure about the background of the problem / text. You may take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT first.

Comment: The lyapunov and Lindberg conditions are what is required for the CLT to hold.  Isn't this a little different because we are alllowing the denominator to be a sequence of reals rather than $Var^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical situation in the sense that we have iid random variables with finite second moments (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT)). We know that
$$
\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{\sqrt n}\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\sigma^2)
$$
as $n\to\infty$, where $\sigma^2=\operatorname{Var}X_1$.

So we need to make sure that the variance of
$$
\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{B_n}
$$
converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. The norming sequence $\{B_n\}$ is going to be equal to $\sigma\sqrt n$ for each $n\ge1$ with some positive constant $\sigma$ that we need to find. This constant $\sigma$ is going to depend on $\alpha$.

I hope this helps.